# WordPress: custom weather API page

Tags: wordpress, plugins, weather-api

I'm going to build a WP site, using a theme as a personal portfolio. My plan is to make a special page called weather with the following functions:

1. It connects with a weather API that detects the visitor's location and the current weather based on its location
2. It displays a random photo of me and a message if it's cold or not

How to do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Good look. Sound like a good plan. You need to start coding and if you face any issues then please post your code and we will help you with that piece of code.

If you need to look on some similar plugins for ideas, you may search and install plugins via WordPress and then study the way plugin author has coded that plugin.

WordPress specifically, You may define a shortcode, which calls a function. And this function you code have all the code which connects weather api and do the logic and presentation part.